# How many sequences are there (Using generating functions)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> How many sequences are there, with the length of $n$ above $\left\{0,1,2,3,4\right\}$ such that the digits sum is $9$.

The solution offers the following generating function for the problem:
$$ (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^n $$

Yet, for my understanding **the order is important** here (sequences). Hence the generating function should be: $$\left(1+x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^n$$

Who's right?

Comment: I do not understand. The generating function will count different orders as different.

Comment: Why do you divide by $k!$?

Comment: More generally, there is a golden rule for this kind of thing. Try your expressions for really simple cases. Does the second expression look correct for $n=1$, for example?

Comment: @Snufsan, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $i$-th $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$ term stands for the value of the $i$-th digit, therefore the terms already takes the order into consideration.

We have $n$ digits -  and therefore $n$ of those terms.

To get the number of valid sequences, you need to find $x^9$ coefficient